# How to print Unicode created from string iteration in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, unicode

I have a loop to create code to print the Unicode characters (I realize I haven't converted 10-a, etc). My point is, after looping to build the Unicode string (in this case Japanese Hiragana) how do I actually get that into a printable character in XCode as any time I try to log it or set a textbox value = to it. It only gives me the string.

```
for (int i=4;i<10;++i) {
  NSString *thirdchar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
  for (int p=0;p<16;++p) {
    NSString *fourthchar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", p];
    NSString *unicode = @"u30";
    unicode = [unicode stringByAppendingString:thirdchar];
    unicode = [unicode stringByAppendingString:fourthchar];
    NSLog(@"unicode \%@", unicode);
  }
}
```

Comment: You might consider either creating a `unichar` variable and using `[NSString stringWithCharacters:myChar length:1]` to make a string from each one, or creating a `char` array with the equivalent UTF-8 byte sequences and using `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:myBytes]`.  The `\uNNNN` substitution probably occurs too soon to support the "dynamic" `\u` sequence that you seem to be constructing.

Comment: @Kevin is right: `@"\uNNNN"` takes effect at compile-time.

Comment: Could you throw a guy a bone for an example.  I tried the unichar variable and I can't seem to get that out.

Comment: I've converted my example into an Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compose the code numerically instead of trying to write a string.

For example, inside your `p` loop:

```
unichar x = (0x3000 + 0x10 * i + p);
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&x length:1];
NSLog(@"unicode %@", str);
```

Comment: You rock my friend although I had to flip to the integer entity 12343(ish) instead of the hex code entity but still I was missing the proper formatting on the unichar which was very very stupid on my end.